# Connect textarea with a POST request in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, http-post

How could I connect the `textarea` to my `POST` request so that I can change the values and send it the `.json` data?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the `textarea`:

```
  <textarea
    value={state}
    onChange={e=> setState(e.target.value)} ...restOfProps>
....
  </textarea>
```

This code updates the state, so you can use the `fetch` and move it outside the `useeffect` in order to make the function async. Afterwards, you could call the function in `useEffect`, since `fetch` is better to be async.

Answer (score 0):

first move the fetch outside the useEffect in a separate function and the call it on send

create a state like
const [data,setData] = useState({})

add onChange event on textArea and inside it assign its value to state variable

assign this state variable to post request body
and on press send button call this function